# Insert specific XML node in specific location using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am looking for a way to insert a specific XML node in a specific location. Below is the example:

```
<Car>
     <Brand>Toyota</Brand>
     <Color>Red</Color>
     <Price>10000</Color>
</Car>
```

Say if I were to want to insert a node `<Year>2012</Year>` in between `<Color>` and `<Price>` node, what should I do?

Do note that replacing whole XML doc is not an option in my current scenario. Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004670/insert-xml-node-before-specific-node-using-c-sharp

Comment: @NoChance Hi, was looking for away to do it through T-SQL directly instead. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that.

Comment: What flavor of SQL? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgre, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use XQuery [`insert ... after ...`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx) statement to insert `Year` element right after `Color` :

```
declare @xml XML = '<Car>
     <Brand>Toyota</Brand>
     <Color>Red</Color>
     <Price>10000</Price>
</Car>'

SET @xml.modify('
    insert <Year>2012</Year>
    after (//Color)[1]
')

SELECT @xml
```

**output :**

```
<Car>
  <Brand>Toyota</Brand>
  <Color>Red</Color>
  <Year>2012</Year>
  <Price>10000</Price>
</Car>
```